# Getting error "contract mismatch - mismatched Actions between sender and receiver"

Tags: wcf

I am consuming a WCF webservice. It's a working service and in my application we are already consuming many methods from the service. I have just added the new method in the working wcf SERVICE. when I test the new method in WCF service it's working fine, there are no issues when I test the service alone. But I have added the new WCF service dll to my web application and trying to consume my new method, I am always getting this error message.

There is no issue with WCF service, because all other methods from the services works fine, excpt the newly added method.

> **Error:**
>   due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)

I have restarted IIS many times, there is no issue while building the project, however in runtime whenever I try to consume new method, I am getting an error message.

```
var response = client.GetAllCountries(new GetAllCountriesRequest
                {
                    Language = "Eng",
                    IndustryCode = "TP"
                });
```

Comment: Is the new service actually deployed to the server?

Comment: yes its deployed to server,

Comment: so do you suspect on the deployment ?

Comment: Well, you clearly have an incompatibility. After changing the contract this error usually means the server is still running the old contract. Post your client and server side config files for more detailed help.